# Using fetch and store value in a global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables, fetch-api

Working on my JavaScript skills I'm stuck on this bit was wondering if anyone could help please?

Objective: is to store value  from request and place it in a globally accessible variable.

```
const CurreField = document.querySelector('#cctype');
const AmountFields = document.querySelector('#curAmount');
let data_test ="";
 

async function getValue() {
const results = await fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
const data = await results.json(); 
const value_pick = data.rates.USD
return value_pick
}



let get_data;
getValue().then(data => {
get_data = data;

});


let value_manipulate = get_data // not sure how to fix this bit
```

// I want to achieve a `console.log(value_manipulate)`

Comment: You are already making `get_data` global ..... BUT.... you can't use it until after the asynchronous promise has resolved

Comment: This is not possible. (Or: you've done it correctly, but were accessing the global variable too early). Instead, store a promise for the result in the global variable, and then wait for it in every place you need it.

Comment: new to this javascript any idea how i would do this?@Bergi
@charlietfl would you recommend a settimeout?

Comment: No...do what you need to with it in the `then()`

Comment: @charlietfl so you recommend doing all my logic in the then instead of working with a global variable? or anything outside the code?

Comment: In general...yes. Doesn't mean you can't store the data global for later access but depends what you are doing in the app. If you only need that data once consume it in the then()

Comment: Cheers @charlietfl for future use what would you recommend if i wish to use it at a later stage?

Comment: Recommend in what regard?

Comment: @charlietfl how can i use and store the data in a global variable which i can use later on?

Comment: You are already storing it in variable named get_data. Important to understand that the request takes time to go to server and back and other code doesn't stop while that happens. That's why promise is used to return something in the future

Comment: @charlietfl yes i agree but the data doesn't come back. it comes as undefined.

Comment: Undefined inside the `then()?

Comment: nope,

let get_data;
getValue().then(data => {

});


console.log(get_data)

Comment: But I just explained ( as does the duplicate link) that you need to consume it inside the then(). You are trying to eat a pizza before it gets delivered when you log it outside then()

Comment: so its not possible to store it outside in a global variable.. and to echo your point its best to work in the then. so how is this possible "Doesn't mean you can't store the data global for later access"

Comment: Later means when needed after user a event for example. Not later in the immediate sequence of the code getting it

Comment: @charlietfl ah i see now  thanks for the clarification  and your time :)